# How to use pymongo for writing/reading to two different mongo servers (with different versions of mongo 2.4 and 3.0.3)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have two mongo databases on two different servers. One server is mongo 2.4 and the other is mongo 3.0.3. How would I get a single python app server to connect and read from both? From pip it looks like I can only install one version of pymongo, thus making it impossible to access both databases.

Does anyone know of a way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/python/) PyMongo 3.0 supports both MongoDB 2.4 and MongoDB 3.0. Thus you just need to create two corresponding [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) instances and use them as you need to.